# Lexus IS250 2008 won't start

Tags: battery, alternator, lexus

Today, I tried to sell my Lexus IS250 2008. I turned the car on and drove to meet the guy. When I got there I let car on idling because I wanted it to warm up (heating was on, seat heating was on, etc.). I talked to him and he looked at the car for around 15 minutes. When I wanted to leave, the steering wheel was very heavy and brake paddle is very stiff. I turned the car off, but it won't start on. The first time, I jump start the car, and it turned on. I went to talk with a guy for 2 minutes, then I came back but the steering wheel was very heavy. I turned it off, and jumped started it again. The steering wheel was light, and I drove back home.

What is the problem? Is it the alternator or the battery?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like an alternator problem. You could check it easily by recharging the battery, then checking the voltage while it's running. If the voltage continually drops, it means the alt isn't putting out juice. Alternately, you could possibly take the alternator to a parts store where they would put it on a machine which would test it for you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thank you for your comment. I hope it is not that expensive.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [information I found online](https://www.edmunds.com/lexus/is-250/2008/features-specs/), your car as electronic brake force distribution and electronic speed-proportinal powersteering. Both features rely on electric power.

The problem is most likely caused by a faulty altenator.